# Spritesheet appearing behind Like button

Tags: facebook-like

In the below image I am getting a sprites-sheet? that is appearing in the background of my Like button? Any ideas on why this might be?  You can see it live at http://MTGPeerTrader.com.

[image: Facebook Like Image with Sprite Sheet in background]

I have tried adding a style to disable this via:

```
background-image:none !important;
```

but it was without effect.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I have it...

You have inline-style so, the `<span style="height: .. px; width: .. px">` just before of the `<iframe id="f3b93e80cc"..` remove `height` and in your stylesheet `#FaceBookGroupLink` put `margin-top: 68px;`

I hope this help you...

Comment: I don't actually generate that, all I do is call the FacebookGroupLink via `<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://mtgpeertrader.com" data-width="40" data-layout="box_count" data-show-faces="false" data-send="false"></div>`